# Is there any possible way to take full page screen shot with include system taskbar date and timestamp in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

When i was taking the screenshot using cypress it was not capturing the task bar system date and time, when i use this code
[Currently using code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr5kz.png)

[Current image without system date and time stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU0bl.png)

Am expecting to take full page screen shot with include system taskbar date and timestamp.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the use case for this? Cypress won't be able to do this on it's own, as Cypress does not have access to the entire window, only the Cypress runner window.